# Realm 3.1.x doesn't notify parent RealmObject when child RealmObject is modified

Tags: android, realm

I have observed a change in behavior in Realm 3.0.0 vs 3.1.0/3.1.1/3.1.2, with respect to RealmObject listeners.

RealmThingA has a field of type RealmThingB.

```
public class RealmThingA extends RealmObject {
    private RealmThingB realmThingB;

    public RealmThingA() {}

    public RealmThingB getRealmThingB() { return realmThingB; }

    public void setRealmThingB(RealmThingB realmThingB) {
        this.realmThingB = realmThingB;
    }
}

public class RealmThingB extends RealmObject {
    private String value;

    public RealmThingB() { }

    public String getValue() { return value; }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

A listener is attached to an instance of RealmThingA.  The 'value' field of RealmThingB is modified.  (I can provide a more complete example, if that helps.)

In Realm 3.0.0 the listener is fired when RealmThingB is modified.  In Realm 3.1.0/3.1.1/3.1.2, the listener is not fired.

Is this an intentional change?  If so, how can I get the previous behavior (listener attached to parent object is notified when child object changes)?

Comment: this is intentional behavior according to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4460#issuecomment-292884450

Comment: A way to restore previous behavior would be to keep a **field** reference to `RealmResults<RealmThingA>` and `RealmResults<RealmThingB>` that are both obtained with `findAll()` or `findAllAsync()`, and apply the same `RealmChangeListener` to both of them.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @EpicPandaForce.  Disappointing...

I guess I'll have to attach the listener to both the parent and child(ren) objects  (RealmResults is not relevant in this case).